MFRC630 - I2C pinout and configuration
In the documentation for the MFRC630 it says that pin 23 is SCL and 24 is SDA.
On page 14 "Host interfaces" it says that IFSEL0 ( pin 26 ) should be set to PAD_VDD and IFSELF1 ( pin 27 ) should be set to VSS to activate the I2C host interface.
But here it also says that SDA is pin 31 and SCL is pin 29.
Which SCL and SDA is correct ones?
Datasheet for the device: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC630.pdf

If you look at the diagram on page 9, you’ll see that the SCL and SDA pins are a separate I2C interface to connect to a SAM. The host interface, which can be either I2C, UART or SPI, goes through pins IF0 to IF3.
Section 8.4, starting on page 14, talks about selecting the host interface.

I got a clarification of the matter by NPX.
The I2C bus connected to pin 23 and 24 is for slave devices, like MIFARE SAM. The SAM can be connected to the microcontroller to operate like a cryptographic co-processor. For details, please read 8.4.5 SAM interface.
Therefore these two pins should not be used by the host at all, they should be connected to the pins mentioned on page 14.
